# Сигнал QProcess для выполнения с использованием сигналов слотов

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты, qprocess

Как можно запустить QProcess по сигналу не используя таймер? В приведённом коде как пока вызванная команда внутри QProcess не выполнится, очередь событий не будет обрабатываться, соответсвенно не отрисовывается окно программы. С таймером понятно как это сделать а как это сделать используя стандартные сигналы класса.

```
qDebug()<<"Set command";
QString path = QDir::homePath()+"/settings.ini";
if (QFile(path).exists())
{
    QSettings settings(path, QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.beginGroup("command");
    QProcess cmdProcess;
    cmdProcess.start(settings.value("com").toString(),settings.value("arg").toStringList());
    cmdProcess.waitForFinished();
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

Comment: просто взять и запустить... релевантный кусок кода с (не) рабочим поведением помог бы вопросу...

Comment: @Fat-Zer дело в то что при запуске должны быть отрисованы окна, но этого не произойдет пока не закончиться QProcess;

Comment: создавай процесс в куче, а не на стеке... и `waitForFinished ()` убери

Comment: По какому сигналу?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin уже сделал спасибо, повесил на такой сигнал connect(cmdProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(processClosed(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));